# How ASE (App service Environment send traffic to Web App services with ILB

Tags: azure

How ASE (App service Environment send traffic to Web App services, We have application gateway and Backup pool setup to send traffic to ASE and how ASE talking to Web app, I'm confused on same. Please help me to understand it.

So Web traffic comes to Application Gateway> Listeners> Rules > Backup pool and Http setting > ASE (App service environment > Web server xyz.com

But I have not found any setting from ASE to Web apps how traffic to reaching from ASE to 9 different apps and how does it know what app traffic belongs to which one. If there any URL or someone can explain please help me.